# Solution of IVP $y'=y^2, y(0) =0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Consider the ordinary differential equation $$y'=y^2, y(0) =0$$

Clearly $y=0$ is a solution of it. Can i say that this is only solution? I tried as follows

Choose rectangle $|x|\leq a, |y|\leq b$, then $|f(x, y) |\leq b^2$ . Now using existence theorem we have $$h=min\{a, \frac{b}{b^2}\}
=\frac{1}{b}\to\infty$$ So by Existence theorem we can say that $y=0$ is a global solution of given differential equation . But I don't know about uniquness of solution. Did I correctly apply Existence theorem? Please suggest. Thank you.

Comment: You do not need an existence theorem because you can see $0$ already exists as a solution.  You would need to apply the uniqueness theorem, or solve the (separable) ODE as in the answer below for a specialized argument about uniqueness.

Comment: @Michael please sir can you comment what I tried is coreect or wrong? It is ok no need to  apply theorem .

Comment: @Michael can you give non trivial solution of given ODE.

Comment: As I said, the existence theorem is not relevant here.  You need to apply the uniqueness theorem.  So you should first state that theorem.  I believe a standard theorem for $y'=f(x,y)$ involves continuity of $f$ and of derivatives of $f$, so you would show those continuity properties hold in this special case.

Comment: @Michael uniqueness theorem says uniqueness locally.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there exist a different solution $y\ne 0$. Then divide both sides of the equation by $y^2$:$$\frac{y'}{y^2}=1$$
Integrating, you get $$-\frac 1y=x+C$$or $$y=-\frac 1{x+C}$$But this can't verify the condition $y(0)=0$ for any finite $C$.

Comment: This argument works only if you assume that $y(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$. Zeros of $y$ make the answer much more complicated.

Comment: @Andrei yours solution does not satisfies given conditions as you said in end then what is use of this solution. Thanks for reply. Please if possible give detailed regarding$y(0) =0$ solution.

Comment: @Andrei can you give non trivial solution of given ODE?

Comment: @Yogesh The only continuous solution is the trivial one, given the initial condition.